# Linux wifi not working

Tags: networking, wifi, drivers

So, i just got a Linux as a dual boot with windows, and i can't get the wi-fi to work. I have a tp-link WN823N card and the integrated intel card, one using a realtek RTL8192EU chipset with the rtl8xxxu driver installed, and the other the basic intel chipset. I tried everything i found, i have the drivers installed, the cards are listed in iwconfig and ifconfig and the strangest thing is that i can use airmon-ng to put the cards in monitor mode, and they also work with airodump-ng and list all the networks nearby yet i can't use any of the cards for normal wireless networking.

Also, here is the full diagnostic report for the network: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NKPY3ssgqg/ . The laptop on which i am running the linux distro is a lenovo legion y530

Comment: Does the wifi work with Windows?

Comment: Yes, it works @TimothyPulliam

Comment: Also what do you mean "can't get the wifi to work". What happens when you try to connect? When you took that diagnostic report, were you connected via Ethernet?

Comment: Yeah,  i was on ethernet when i took the report, and when i try to open any of the 2 network adapters they just instantly shut back down. @TimothyPulliam

Answer (score 1):

Ok, seems like i've been able to solve the problem by simply making a new wpa supplicant via terminal and connecting to it with 
`wpa_supplicant -D -i -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -B`
The trouble is that the network still appears as unavailable in the network manager up the right corner. Tho, internet is working, which is, very very strange. If anyone knows how to fix this, it would be amazing, for now I think i can live with crontabbing those lines to connect to the internet.